# Preserve files in /tmp using systemd in 15.04

Tags: 15.04, tmp, systemd

If possible I'd like to preserve /tmp/foo/* across boots. My attempts at configuring tmpfiles.d have been unsuccessful. As root I created `/etc/tmpfiles.d/foo.conf` with contents:

```
x /tmp/foo/*
```

XOR

```
X /tmp/foo - - - - -
```

XOR

```
x /tmp/foo - - - - -
```

None of those edits worked.

According to `man tmpfiles.d` the x stands for "Ignore a path during cleaning," which is exactly what I'd like to do. In that man page there is even an example (#2) about how to accomplish this.

However, on reboot, /tmp/foo is always missing. What am I doing wrong? Is tmpfiles.d the way to accomplish this in 15.04?

Comment: Of course, you are leading answerers up the garden path if [`/tmp` is a tmpfs on your system for some reason](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1392637).  So you'd better tell everyone what filesystem `/tmp` is on.

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
x /tmp/foo - - - - -
```

But note this:

```
Note that lines of this type do not influence the effect of r or R lines.
```

man page:

```
r

Remove a file or directory if it exists. This may not be used to 
remove non-empty directories, use R for that. Lines of this type 
accept shell-style globs in place of normal path names. Does not 
follow symlinks.

R

Recursively remove a path and all its subdirectories (if it is a 
directory). Lines of this type accept shell-style globs in place of 
normal path names. Does not follow symlinks.



x

Ignore a path during cleaning. Use this type to exclude paths from 
clean-up as controlled with the Age parameter. Note that lines of this 
type do not influence the effect of r or R lines. Lines of this type 
accept shell-style globs in place of normal path names.

The configuration format is one line per path containing type, path, 
mode, ownership, age, and argument fields:

     #Type Path        Mode UID  GID  Age Argument
     d    /run/user   0755 root root 10d -
     L    /tmp/foobar -    -    -    -   /dev/null

Fields may be enclosed within quotes and contain C-style escapes.
```

[Source](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html)

Comment: I edited `/etc/tmpfiles.d/foo.conf` to read `x /tmp/foo`, and /tmp/foo was not preserved. Is this what you meant? I appreciate you helping me fix this.

Comment: Post the full line

Comment: That is the full line. Do I need more?

Comment: Answer has an update

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: `X /tmp/foo - - - - -` nor `x /tmp/foo - - - - -` worked in `/etc/tmpfiles.d/foo.conf`.

Comment: Now I'm completely confused x X aaah. :/

Comment: Try the lower x

Comment: @afspear Updated my answer.